# How to convert keyboard module number into char?

Tags: python, module, keyboard, key

I've been working on a python project using the keyboard module and socket to control a computer from another. In order for it to work, the keyboard of the server computer is blocked, so that if you hit windows, it opens on the other PC but not the server. Keyboard.is_pressed() works even when key_block is active, however if I check every key using for i in range(150): with is_pressed(), I can't find a way to convert i back to a character. E.g. is_pressed(30) is a, but I don't know how to convert 30 back to a efficiently.

```html
import keyboard
import time

for key in range(150):
  keyboard.block_key(key)
  
target_time = time.time() + 10
while time.time() < target_time:
  for key in range(150):
    if keyboard.is_pressed(key):
      print("Key %s is pressed." % key)
      #Heres the problem - that returns a numeric value which I need to convert into a, b, c, win, etc.
```

Comment: Maybe the docs can help https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardget_typed_stringsevents-allow_backspacetrue

Also, `chr()` built-in function might help, but not sure.

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the docs - I tried the `chr()` function but for some reason the keyboard module doesn't use the same numeric values. E.g. 30 with keyboard module returns a, 30 with `chr()` returns \xle (no idea what that is)